# How to customize error function of MATLAB Neural Network

Tags: matlab, customization, neural-network

I want to implement this function as the error function for training a neural network:

```
function err = MyErrorFunction(T,O)
  d = T - O;
  err = -d*( exp(-d) - 1 );
end
```

where `T` is target value and `O` is neural network output for an input.

The training algorithm doesn't matter (apparently error function for `trainlm` is not customizable, so I can go with the `trainscg`).

I've found [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2VFDSE/index.html?product=NN&solution=1-2VFDSE) that suggests using the `template_performance.m` file to define a new performance function. I says I just have copy this file and customize it as I want.

<del>But as I have understood, `template_performance.m` is a template for **performance** function, not the **error** function: `template_performance.m` gets the error values and output a performance value, for instance it could sum up the square of the errors and output them (SSE).</del>

Apparently, `template_performance.m` have been deprecated starting from MATLAB 2010.

So, how I can change the way that error/performance is calculated/evaluated when training a neural network?

Comment: can you link the article you mentioned?

Comment: Here is the article:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2VFDSE/index.html?product=NN&solution=1-2VFDSE

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem ... the whole thing about customizing a performance function is a total disaster. A lot of stuff is being depreciated and there is zero documentation on what we *should* do.

I ended up having to hack the core files of a performance function I wasn't planning on using (SSE). Under the matlab directory `MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnperformance` you can find them. I modified the apply.m (in the SSE+ folder) function with some directional weights based on `t`, `t-1` change. But then I ran into the problem of training algorithms sending parameters to `apply()` in a different way AND format than `perform()`. I ended up not using `perform()` and writing my own code for that. Jesus... Total mess.

This was a very ugly hack and I'd love to hear from anyone who found the correct way to do this.

Comment: Same here. Custom performance functions are a pain to implement. Since there is no documentation and vanilla implementations are not documented, it's reverse engineering problem. If anyone has insight, am eager to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the performance function is used both for training and testing/evaluation (unless a certain training algorithm is hard-coded to a specific function)

Comment: Correct. I am not looking for a way to implement different performance function in training/test. I am looking for a way to **customize** the error function. Please read the question carefully. More details about the question is also available here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311783#849948

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but isn't the training algorithm working on the output of the performance function (not the error/difference value directly) and trying to optimize it as objective? If so it should be sufficient to implement your custom performance function. The first argument it receives `E` "error" is the difference between targets and outputs, and that will be used directly in your equation `perf = -E*(exp(-E)-1)`... You should know that starting from MATLAB R2010b, all these functions have been deprecated.

Comment: You are right. The performance function *is* actually what I am looking for. But apparently this solution (using `template_performance`) is obsolete for MATLAB 2010 and above. So, any other idea?